# Questions about the imagefield of CCK

Tags: entities

1. How can I include the text between the label of image field and the upload button?
2. How can I remove the text "maximum file size" of the image field in some content types? I want to remove the text "maximum file size" but I want to keep "allowed extensions."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that you are talking about the 'edit form', you can use css to control the visibility of these fields in this way:

```
/*---------------------------
this rule is to hide the text
"maximum file size"
and "allowed extensions"*/

div#edit-field-cl-namefiled-upload-wrapper div#edit-field-namefiled-upload-wrapper div.description{
display:none;
}

/*---------------------------
this rule is to move your description
near to the field to upload.
here you can add the "allowed extensions.." text*/

div#edit-field-namefiled-upload-wrapper > div.description{
margin-top:-70px;
position:absolute;
}
```